# Proving $\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}$ and $p$ are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

For two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in a path-connected component, we know that their fundamental groups are isomorphic. In other words $$\pi_1(X,x_1)\cong\pi_1(X,x_2)$$

Let $\alpha$ be a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$. Also, let $p$ be a loop at $x_1$. Can we say $\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}$ and $p$ are homotopic?

One would be tempted to say the following:

We can prove that $\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}$ and $p$ are homotopic by proving $[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]=[p]$. Now $[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]=[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]*[p]*[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]$, and clearly $[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]=[e_{x_1}]$. Hence $[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]=[e_{x_1}]*[p]*[e_{x_1}]=[p]$.

1. Are $\alpha*\alpha^{-1}*p*\alpha*\alpha^{-1}$ and $p$ homotopic?
2. I am not convinced with the validity of the above argument. Could someone comment on the validity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your $e_{x_2}$'s should be $e_{x_1}$; you never see an $\alpha^{-1} * \alpha$. Also, the notation $[\gamma_1] * [\gamma_2]$ is a bit weird: you concatenate loops, but you *multiply* homotopy classes so $[\gamma_1][\gamma_2]$ would be the more natural thing to write. Also, $[e_{x_1}]$ is the identity element in the group, so you could just remove it from the products; does this convince you?

Comment: If $p$ is a loop at $x_1$, then $\alpha \ast p \ast \alpha^{-1}$ is a loop at $x_2$. This defines a map $f(p)$ for loops. Check that it preserves homotopy class, then it's defined on the classes (i.e. between $\pi_1(X,x_1)$ and $\pi_1(X, x_2)$). Then check the isomorphism properties.

Comment: @fuglede- Thanks for your answer. 1. $[\alpha*\alpha^{-1}]$ is a homotopy class that starts and ends at $x_1$. Why should it not equal $[e_{x_1}]$? 2. I am following notation as given in Munkres' book (and also other online articles like [this](http://people.brandeis.edu/~cherveny/34Afall11/chap9.pdf)). 3. How exactly does the removing follow from first principles is what I'm trying to understand here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- That is exactly the proof that brought me here. I know and understand the proof. However, to develop a more visual and direct understanding of the isomorphism between homotopy classes in path-connected components, I'm trying to find a loop on $x_1$ (going to $x_2$) for every arbitrary loop on $x_1$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: It *should* equal $[e_{x_1}]$ (assuming that by $e_{x_1}$ you mean the constant loop). What I was saying was that you have in your question an $e_{x_2}$, which should have been an $e_{x_1}$.